# SQL query using Spark and java language

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark

I have two dataframe on spark .

```
The first dataframe1 is : 
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|id_z          |longitude     |latitude      |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|[12,20,30 ]   |-7.0737816    | 33.82666     |
|13            |-7.5952683    | 33.5441916   |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+

The second dataframe2 is : 
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|id_z2         |longitude2    |latitude2      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 14           |-8.5952683    | 38.5441916    |
| 12           |-7.0737816    | 33.82666      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I want to apply the logic of the following request.

```
String sql =   "SELECT * FROM dataframe2  WHERE dataframe2 .id_z2 IN ("'"
            + id_z +"'") and longitude2 = "'"+longitude+"'" and latitude = "'"+latitude+"'"";
```

I prefer not to have a join, is it possible to do this?
I really need your help ,  or just a starting point that will make things easier for me.

Thnak you

Comment: Why you not prefer join, any reason ??

Comment: just for performance .

Comment: you should explode values of `id_z` and the perform these sql with `=` instead of `IN` statement.